# Find the cosine of the angle between two curves and also find where they intersect

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, vectors

> Find the cosine of the angle between the curves $\langle 0,t^2,t \rangle$ and $\langle cos\left(\pi \frac{t}{2}\right)$,$sin \left(\pi \frac{t}{2} \right)$,$t \rangle$ where they intersect.

To solve this I first found the point of intersection by setting each of the respective components equal to each other.

$0 = cos \left(\frac{\pi u}{2}\right)$ solving this equation gives $1=u$

$t^2 = sin \left(\frac{\pi u}{2} \right)$ solving this equation gives $1=u$

$t = u$ solving this equations gives $1=u$

Putting this together I can see that my point of intersection is $\left( 0,1,1\right)$  Now to find the cosine of the angle between those curves I know I need the derivatives of those two vectors:

$\langle 0,2t,1 \rangle$ and $\langle -sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right), cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right), 1 \rangle$

From here, though, I'm not sure how to calculate the cosine of the angle between the two curves.  Any hints?

Comment: The second derivative (that is, the first derivative of the second curve) needs factors of $\pi/2$ outside of $\sin$ & $\cos$.

Comment: Also your derivation of the intersection point is wrong (there are many solutions to $\cos\theta=0$), though the final result $t=u=1$ is right.

Answer (score 0):

The dot product of two vectors, u, v, is give by $u\cdot v= |u||v|cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors.  At t= 1, the two tangent vectors are <0, 1, 1> and <-1, 0, 1>.

Comment: I thought the tangent vectors were the derivatives of the given vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have found the derivative vectors, at the intersection point $(0,2,1)$ and $(-1,0,1)$ render them unitary.
Thereafter their dot product will be the cosine of the angle between the two curves, at the intersection point.